Project shows error when deploy it on render or netlify? "Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
    ----- Native stack trace -----
     1: 0xb84bd6 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
     2: 0xefec30 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
     3: 0xefef17 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
     4: 0x1110925  [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
     5: 0x1110eb4 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
     6: 0x1127da4 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*) [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
     7: 0x11285bc v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
     8: 0x112a71a v8::internal::Heap::HandleGCRequest() [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
     9: 0x1095d87 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
    10: 0x153743a v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/render/project/nodes/node-20.12.2/bin/node]
    11: 0x7f6407ed9ef6 
    ==> Build failed 

I have developed a MERN project. I want to deploy it, and I have successfully deployed the backend, but the frontend part which are built on ReactJS, having some issues as shown above.
I can easily run my app with the backend live on the server on render.
My react package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^32.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^4.0.0",
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.12.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
    ]
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}

Any suggestions so I can deploy it anywhere on the internet? I can access it from anywhere.
Please reply I am looking for an answer from 1 week :)

Does this answer your question? FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in Ionic 3
